# Visual Studio 2010 Web Conf Tool Error

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-config

I have installed VS 2010 Professional on my laptop and I am having a problem using the Web Configuration Tool. When I try to go to the "Security" tab, it shows me this message.

```
There is a problem with your selected data store. This can be caused by an invalid server name or credentials, or by insufficient permission. It can also be caused by the role manager feature not being enabled. Click the button below to be redirected to a page where you can choose a new data store. 

The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

I am using the default database provided by ASP to handle the user authorization, so the data store that I used was AspNetSqlProvider.

Here is the content of the web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <roleManager enabled="true">
      <providers/>
    </roleManager>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

The tool worked fine on our college Lab's PC. I really don't understand what's wrong and I can't do my assignment because of this. I have searched around and the people with this kind of problem usually forget to enable roleManager, or using their own custom database. None of the solution appears to be working for my current situation. Please help! Thanks!

EDIT: FYI, there's already a user in the database, which I added using this tool on my college Lab's PC. I can login just fine when I run the website. But accessing the security tab in the tool keep giving me error.

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
<roleManager enabled="true">
  <providers/>
</roleManager>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```